# Find all primes p and q such that $343p^3-q^3$ is also a prime

Tags: prime-numbers, exponentiation

> Find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that $343p^3-q^3$ is also a prime.

I have no idea where to start. Does $343=7^3$ help?

Comment: a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)

Comment: $343p^3 - q^3$ is even if $p$ and $q$ are both odd.  One of the following is true: $p = 2 or q=2$ or $343p^3 - q^3 = 2$

Comment: @DougM The second one. If p=2 q=2, then it would be 2744-8 which is even, so it is not prime.

Comment: @GerardL. Sorry if that wasn't clear,  Either $p=2$ or $q=2$ or $(7p)^3 -q^3 = 2$

Comment: And why equal 2? Couldn't be some other prime?

Comment: Well, without a definite p/q value I dont know...

Comment: $2$ is the only even prime. I say, one of $(p,q, 343p^3-q^3)$ must be even.  And since all are prime, one must equal $2.$

Comment: This is getting tiring. Is there a straightforward answer?

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution and prove it is the only one. Because of the "also" in the title we assume $p$ and $q$ primes.We consider only positive primes.
$$343p^3-q^3=\text{ prime }\\(7p)^3-q^3=(7p-q)(49p^2+7pq+q^2)=\text{ prime }$$ This is possible only if $$(7p-q)=1\text{ and } 49p^2+7pq+q^2=\text{ prime }\\(7p-q)=\text{ prime }\text{ and } 49p^2+7pq+q^2=1$$

The second case is easily seen to be impossible hence we have
 the system $$\begin{cases}7p-q=1\\49p^2+7pq+q^2=\text{ prime }\end{cases}$$
 Because of the particular solution $(p,q)=(1,6)$ the general solution of the first equation is
$$\begin{cases}p=t+1\\q=7t+6\end{cases}$$ It follows we have to get prime solutions of the diophantine equation
$$147t^2+273t+127=r\text{ prime }$$ with the restriction $t+1$ and $7t+6$ primes.

A solution is given for $t=1$. We have $$147+273+127=547$$ thus the solution
$$\color{red}{(p,q,r)=(2,13,547)}$$ 
On the other hand, if $t$ is even then $q$ is even greater than $2$ and if $t$ is odd and greater than $1$ then $p$ is even greater than $2$. In both cases $p$ and $q$ cannot be both prime as required. Thus the given solution is the only one.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Write $343p^3-q^3=(7p)^3-q^3$. Now use $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$.

Comment: So $a$ would be 7p?

Comment: And the whole expression would be $(7p-q)(49p^2+7p^3q^3+q^6)$

Comment: @GerardL., yes but concentrate on the possible divisors of a prime number.  Don't forget negative divisors.

Comment: @GerardL. Yes...and then you wrote $\;343p^3-q^3\;$ as a product, so what **must** be each factor in that product to have a prime...?

Comment: @DonAntonio One factor must be 1?

Comment: @lhf What's the whole solution?